# AWS CloudFormation "API: autoscaling:CreateAutoScalingGroup "

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I try to deploy an nodegroup for a EKS Cluster but i have a error with scalingroup module.

This is part of the yml:

```html
Resources:
  NodeInstanceRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - !FindInMap [PartitionMap, !Ref "AWS::Partition", EC2ServicePrincipal]
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Policies:
          - PolicyName: !Sub "Test-permisosec2"
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: "Allow"
                  Action:
                    - 'ec2:CreateTags'
                    - 'ec2:RunInstances'
                    - 'iam:GetRole'
                    - 'iam:PassRole'
                    - 'autoscaling:CreateAutoScalingGroup'
                  Resource:
                    - '*'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess"
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AutoScalingFullAccess"
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"
      Path: /

  NodeInstanceProfile:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile"
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - !Ref NodeInstanceRole

 #####
  NodeLaunchTemplate:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate"
    Properties:
      TagSpecifications:
        - ResourceType: launch-template 
          Tags:
          - Key: ID-APP
            Value: 11
          - Key: VERTICAL
            Value: ADQ
          - Key: ENTORNO
            Value: SANDBOX_IT
      LaunchTemplateData:
        TagSpecifications:
        - ResourceType: instance
          Tags:
          - Key: ID-APP
            Value: 11
          - Key: VERTICAL
            Value: ADQ
          - Key: ENTORNO
            Value: SANDBOX_IT
        - ResourceType: network-interface
          Tags:
          - Key: ID-APP
            Value: 11
          - Key: VERTICAL
            Value: ADQ
          - Key: ENTORNO
            Value: SANDBOX_IT
        - ResourceType: volume 
          Tags:
          - Key: ID-APP
            Value: 11
          - Key: VERTICAL
            Value: ADQ
          - Key: ENTORNO
            Value: SANDBOX_IT         
        BlockDeviceMappings:
          - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
            Ebs:
              DeleteOnTermination: true
              VolumeSize: !Ref NodeVolumeSize
              VolumeType: gp2
        IamInstanceProfile:
          Arn: !GetAtt NodeInstanceProfile.Arn
        ImageId: !If
          - HasNodeImageId
          - !Ref NodeImageId
          - !Ref NodeImageIdSSMParam
        InstanceType: !Ref NodeInstanceType
        KeyName: !Ref KeyName
        SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
        UserData: !Base64
          "Fn::Sub": |
            #!/bin/bash
            set -o xtrace
            /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${ClusterName} ${BootstrapArguments}
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal --exit-code $? \
                     --stack  ${AWS::StackName} \
                     --resource NodeGroup  \
                     --region ${AWS::Region}
        MetadataOptions:
          HttpPutResponseHopLimit : 2
          HttpEndpoint: enabled
          HttpTokens: !If
            - IMDSv1Disabled
            - required
            - optional
##########
  NodeGroup:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
    Properties:
      DesiredCapacity: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity
      MaxSize: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupMaxSize
      MinSize: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupMinSize
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref NodeLaunchTemplate
        Version: !GetAtt NodeLaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
          Value: !Sub ${ClusterName}-${NodeGroupName}-Node
        - Key: !Sub kubernetes.io/cluster/${ClusterName}
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
          Value: owned
        - Key: ID-APP
          PropagateAtLaunch: true 
          Value: 11
        - Key: ENTORNO
          PropagateAtLaunch: true 
          Value: 11
        - Key: VERTICAL
          PropagateAtLaunch: true 
          Value: ADQ
      VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref Subnets
    UpdatePolicy:
      AutoScalingRollingUpdate:
        MaxBatchSize: 1
        MinInstancesInService: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity
        PauseTime: PT5M
```

And this is the error:

[Error CF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgZCp.png)

I Try different permission config but i think the problem is other because with AdministratorAccess Role doesnt work.

Could someone give me some help?

Thanks!

Comment: The error is clear. You have **no permissions** to create such template.

Comment: And this permission where i need to configure? because this .yml is deploy with my user who is administrator and the role in the template "NodeInstanceRole" have "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess". In this part i lost  :(

Answer (score 0):

Check if `NodeImageId` parameter is a valid and existing AMI. Its common mistake to provide AMI from different region.